# Algorithm to identify keys and values from cli string outputs

Tags: python, algorithm, language-agnostic, string-comparison

I have a command `show interface transciever` whose output might vary.
I have collected some of the sample outputs for this command for different scenarios.

```
Ethernet1/2
    transceiver is present
    type is 1000base-T
    name is CISCO-METHODE
    part number is SP7041-E-R
    revision is --
    serial number is MTC19350BBK
    nominal bitrate is 1300 MBit/sec
    Link length supported for copper is 100 m
    cisco id is 3
    cisco extended id number is 4

Ethernet1/3
    transceiver is present
    type is 1000base-T
    name is CISCO-METHODE
    part number is SP7041-E
    revision is E
    serial number is MTC150303LW
    nominal bitrate is 1300 MBit/sec
    Link length supported for copper is 100 m
    cisco id is 3
    cisco extended id number is 4

Ethernet1/4
    transceiver is present
    type is 1000base-T
    name is CISCO-METHODE
    part number is SP7041-E
    revision is E
    serial number is MTC1731072M
    nominal bitrate is 1300 MBit/sec
    Link length supported for copper is 100 m
    cisco id is 3
    cisco extended id number is 4

Ethernet1/5
    transceiver is not present

Ethernet1/6
    transceiver is not present

Ethernet1/7
    transceiver is present
    type is 10Gbase-SR
    name is CISCO-AVAGO
    part number is SFBR-709SMZ-CS1
    revision is G4.1
    serial number is AVD1718A4WN
    nominal bitrate is 10300 MBit/sec
    Link length supported for 50/125um OM2 fiber is 82 m
    Link length supported for 62.5/125um fiber is 26 m
    Link length supported for 50/125um OM3 fiber is 300 m
    cisco id is 3
    cisco extended id number is 4
    cisco part number is 10-2415-03
    cisco product id is SFP-10G-SR
    cisco vendor id is V03
```

^^ Some of the samples. 
I want compare these different samples and identify the potential keys and values.

Like:

- transceiver is present
- transceiver is not present

**`transceiver is`** can be the key and **`present/not present`** can be the value.
Similarly I would like to parse these output samples to identify other keys and values. Is there a ***standard algorithm*** which can take me in the right direction to achieve this.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Check if the tool has an option to produce machine-readable output. Many modern CLI tools can output JSON or XML with a command-line switch.

Comment: @tripleee unfortunately its not available, these cli tools were developed long time back

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about a *standard algorithm*, but for this example it looks like you should search for instances of `' is '`  and define the key as the preceding text and the value as the subsequent text.

Here is an example:

```
# Sample data
string = '''Ethernet1/2
    transceiver is present
    type is 1000base-T
    name is CISCO-METHODE
    part number is SP7041-E-R
    revision is --
    serial number is MTC19350BBK
    nominal bitrate is 1300 MBit/sec
    Link length supported for copper is 100 m
    cisco id is 3
    cisco extended id number is 4'''

sub = string.split('\n')

d = {}
d[sub[0]] = [x.strip() for x in sub[1:]]

e = {}
for key in d.keys():
    e[key] = {}
    for item in d[key]:
        new = item.split(' is ')
        e[key][new[0]] = new[1]
print(e)
```

```
{'Ethernet1/2': 
    {'transceiver': 'present', 
     'type': '1000base-T', 
     'name': 'CISCO-METHODE', 
     'part number': 'SP7041-E-R', 
     'revision': '--', 
     'serial number': 'MTC19350BBK', 
     'nominal bitrate': '1300 MBit/sec', 
     'Link length supported for copper': '100 m', 
     'cisco id': '3', 
     'cisco extended id number': '4'}}
```

If there are instances that have more than one level, you could identify those by additional parsing, such as searching for instances of `' for '` and repeating the process.

Comment: thanks for the help, but I dont want to generalize the solution by parsing using specific keyword like `is` or `for`. This is just one cli what we are trying to develop is a generic parser for many other cli tools as well, and there is no uniform output structure across different cli tools.

Comment: There is no universal algorithm because different tools have different conventions. Writing a parser for each specific format seems unavoidable; or you have material for a good PhD if you want to try anyway.

Comment: @madcolonel10 What *can* be assumed about the data you want to parse? That the keys/values are each contained on a single line? That they key always comes first? That there are more occurrences of each specific key than there are unique values for that key?

Comment: @tripleee i was thinking of using https://github.com/devongovett/regexgen. I was planning to generate a regular expression for unique line from all samples, and after regex is generated (for e.g `/transeiver is (?:not )?present/`) I was planning to extract the non regex part from it. Do you think this can be a good approach

Comment: @Nathaniel we cannot assume that key always comes first, for now we can assume key and value is on the same line